# PayPal 3rd party shopping cart - how to add one flat shipping charge for cart

Tags: paypal, cart

I'd like to charge a flat shipping charge for the entire cart. I can do that with tax by using the "tax_cart" variable but can't find the equivalent for a shipping charge. My code is shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

```xml
<form class="paypalform"
      action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bn/cgi-bin/webscr"
      method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@gmail.com">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@count" value="@item.ProductName">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_@count" value="@item.Price">
        
        count++;
        cartTotal += @item.Price;
    }  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">             
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="@ViewBag.TaxAmount" />           
    <input type="image"
           src="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif"
           name="submit"
           alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set variable "shipping" and "shipping2" to define shipping charge.

[Magento - PayPal Plus and Zero Subtotal Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151046/magento-paypal-plus-and-zero-subtotal-checkout/48163646#48163646)

Comment: I had assumed those were applied to individual items. Tried it out and it works perfectly. Thanks