# Magento - PayPal Plus and Zero Subtotal Checkout

Tags: paypal, magento2

I'm having problems with Zero Subtotal checkout and Paypal Plus. I have some products with Zero cost, and when I try to buy it the button "Place Order" is disabled.

But when I disable Paypal Plus, it works normally.

I'm using Magento 2.1.5 and this module: https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus

Someone already suffered with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Amount is always requested to more than zero. You can set 0.01 (or the equivalent minimum amount for other currency) if you want to show your customer free payment. Or, you can refund.